# couchdb Save with cradle api and iriscouch follow api not working in NodeJS function

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cradle, iriscouch

I am trying to save a javascript object with cradle in NodeJS but I do not get a response or an error message after the save. Its a local couchdb with no password set. The connection is ok and the database exists. 
I am also using iriscouch follow https://github.com/iriscouch/follow . So when a change is made in the wages table the save employee method  is called. The follow works, as I have debugged it but no save is taking place.

Here is my code.

```
var employeedb = new(cradle.Connection)().database('employees');

employeedb.exists(function (err, exists) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error', err);
    } else if (exists) {
        console.log('Database exists');
    } else {
        console.log('database does not exists.');
        db.create();
        /* populate design documents */
    }
});

follow({db:"http://localhost:5984/wages", include_docs:true}, function(error, change) {
    if(!error) {
    var employee ={};
    employee.name = 'Tom';
    saveEmployee(employee);
 }
})

// simple callback after cradle save
function saveHandler(er, doc){
    if (er) return console.log('Error: ', er);
    console.log(doc);
}

function saveEmployee(employee){
    //need to check if result exists for that runner and event
    var returnData = {};
    employeedb.save(employee, saveHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me, I needed to add

```
var cradle = require('cradle');
```

to the top of your code, and change

```
- employeedb.save(result, saveHandler);
+ employeedb.save(employee, saveHandler);
```

for it to 'compile', but after that it adds Tom to the database.

Comment: Thanks Petter, Sorry I should have been more specific with my question. I have updated it to include the follow function.

Comment: The code still works for me, are you are sure this is the part where your program fails? I'm accessing couchDB locally with full privileges, are you sure you're allowed to add documents to your database?

Comment: yes database is ok as when i add the code var employee ={};
    employee.name = 'Tom';
    saveEmployee(employee); outside of the follow it saves correctly.

Comment: Hi Petter, thanks for your help on this. I finally have it working. I was using webstorm debugger and was expecting the database creation to happen after it ran through the breakpoint. When i ran the program without the debugger I got an exception somewhere else in the code so no update was to the DB was taking place.